# ipython: showing CWD in prompt

Tags: ipython

In `ipython`, I have changed the prompt to show hostname and current working directory, to emulate system shell (bash):

```
c.PromptManager.in_template = '\\h:\\w '
```

this works well, except for a small detail. When I am in my home (`/home/martin`) it shows the full path, instead of the customary `~`:

```
alpha:/home/martin
```

instead of

```
alpha:~
```

is it possible to change to `~` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
c.PromptManager.in_template = '\\h:\\Xn '
```

where $n=0 .. 5.$ The current working directory, with $HOME replaced by ~, and filtered out to contain only $n$ path elements

so for example, you can use:

```
c.PromptManager.in_template = '\\h:\\X5 '
```